# Unable to Print data in listview in android after Json Parsing

Tags: android

```
public class Setting extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    ListView listView1;
    ImageView backbutton;
    String Url = "http://182.71.212.110:8083/api/values/userdetails";
    String Id;
    String Designation;
    String EmployeeName;
    JSONArray _jarray;

    List<RowItem> rowItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.setting);
        listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        backbutton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backbutton);
        backbutton.setOnClickListener(this);

        new GetUserdetail().execute();


        CustomList adapter = new CustomList(this, rowItems);
        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (v.getId() == R.id.backbutton) {
            finish();
        }
    }

    class GetUserdetail extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                String json = HttpHitter.ExecuteData(Url);
             _jarray = new JSONArray(json);
                System.out.println("_jarray" + _jarray);

                for (int i = 0; i <= _jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject _obj = _jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    Id = _obj.getString("Id");
                    Designation = _obj.getString("Designation");
                    EmployeeName = _obj.getString("EmployeeName");
                    System.out.println(Id + "" + Designation + ""
                            + EmployeeName);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();


        }
    }

}
```

This my code i am able to display the value after Jason parsing in this line    System.out.println(Id + "" + Designation + ""
                            + EmployeeName);

But i am unable to print data in Listview there is Error coming while i have created 
Datamodel

```
public class RowItem {

    public RowItem(String title, String desc) {

        this.title = title;
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    private String title;
    private String desc;
}
```

I have create adapter which i s extending from Base adapter that work fine can u please tell me how to bind value and display in list view after Json Parsing please suggest me i m trying to Implement .

Comment: its not json its xml dear

Comment: Use http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html instead

Comment: i am able to get data am facing problem to bind in lisview

Answer (score 1):

Use `Custom Adapter` for binding your **JSON data to your Listview** like below :

```
public class ListViewAdapterForLead extends BaseAdapter {
   Context context;
   LayoutInflater inflater;
   ArrayList<SpinnerNavItem> data;
   TextView txtText;


   public ListViewAdapterForLead(Context context,ArrayList<SpinnerNavItem> arraylist) {
       this.context = context;
       data = arraylist;

   }

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
       return data.size();
   }

   @Override
   public Object getItem(int index) {
       return data.get(index);
   }

   @Override
   public long getItemId(int position) {
       return position;
   }

   public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_lead, null);
    }


    txtText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textLeadMenu);



    txtText.setText(data.get(position).getTitle());
    return convertView;




   }



   public View getDropDownView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent){

       if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_lead, null);
        }


        txtText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textLeadMenu);


        txtText.setText(data.get(position).getTitle());


    return convertView;

    }
 }
```

Comment: That i have done @Gulnaz Ghanchi i am having Problem in doninbackground and onPost executed here is my http://pastie.org/9755703 custom view

Comment: write your **`System.out.println(Id + "" + Designation + ""+ EmployeeName);`** line  in your post execute.

Answer (score 0):

bind your values in the `getView()` method of your custom adapter.

Comment: That also working But i am unable to add Datamodel to data in Preexcute methdo

Comment: i am having problem to print data in listview

Answer (score 0):

You should set the data after the background task gets completed.
* First try to set list adapter in onPostExecute() method.
* Make sure all the details in your model gets filled.
* Make use of getView() method in your Adapter class to parse the data.
For sample code for ListView with BaseAdapter, refer the below link
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: i am having problem to Bind data inRowitem

Comment: Add it on globle inside AsyncTask class
ArrayList<RowItem> mArrayList = new ArrayList<RowItem>();

Then try to add inside doBackground method
RowItem rItem = new RowItem(EmployeeName, Designation);
mArrayList.add(rItem);

Answer (score 0):

You forgot one thing,this is why the List is empty

Add the parsed data to your List

```
 //initialize your list here
 rowItems = new List<RowItems>();

     for (int i = 0; i <= _jarray.length(); i++) {

                         JSONObject _obj = _jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                            RowItemsr = new RowItems();
                        Id = _obj.getString("Id");
                        Designation = _obj.getString("Designation");
                        EmployeeName = _obj.getString("EmployeeName");
                        System.out.println(Id + "" + Designation + ""
                                + EmployeeName);
                       // you must create an object and add it to your list
                         r.setTitle(EmployeeName);
                         r.setDesc(Designation);
                        rowItems.add(r);
                    }
```

This is what you need